# Interaction between-Service-Controller-Directive AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-service

What is happening here is some menu items are enabled and some are disabled in the ui. So when user clicks on a menu item which is disabled it gives an error on the page.

I tried to solve the issue using angularjs-service and $broadcast. Now the thing is since every page including the left menu has different controllers so i needed to repeat the $broadcast data to every controller. All I am looking forward to is how can I remove this redundancy?

Left-Menu-Service.js

```
'use strict';
angular.module("MainApp")
.factory('menuClick', function($rootScope) {
    var sharedService = {};
    sharedService.notify = {};

    sharedService.prepForBroadcast = function(msg) {
        this.broadcastItem();
    };
    sharedService.broadcastItem = function() {
        $rootScope.$broadcast('handleBroadcast');
    };
    return sharedService;
});
```

Left-Menu-Controller.js

```
 'use strict';
  angular.module("MainApp")
.controller('LeftMenuCtrl', function ($scope, $rootScope, menuClick) {
        $scope.handleMenuClick = function(action) {
        menuClick.notify.warningNotify =  true;
        menuClick.notify.errorNotify =  true;
        menuClick.notify.successNotify =  true;

        if(!action.IsEnabled)
        {
            menuClick.notify.warningNotify = false;
            menuClick.notify.warningMessage = "This operation is disabled ( "+action.Text+" )";
            menuClick.prepForBroadcast(menuClick.notify);
        }
    };

});
```

Left-Menu.html

```
<li>
    <a ng-click="handleMenuClick(submenu)">{{submenu.Text}}</a>
</li>
```

Notification-Directive.js

```
'use strict';
angular.module("MainApp")
.directive('notification', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: function (tElement, tAttrs) {
            if (tAttrs.type) {
                switch (tAttrs.type){
                    case 'error':
                        return 'partials/template/show_error.html';
                        break;
                    case 'success':
                        return 'partials/template/show_success.html';
                        break;
                    case 'warning':
                        return 'partials/template/show_warning.html';
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

    };
});
```

show_error.html

```
<div ng-hide="notify.errorNotify" ng-init="notify.errorNotify=true">

    <button type="button" ng-click="notify.errorNotify = !notify.errorNotify"></button>
    <h2>{{notify.errorMessage}}</h2>

</div>
```

Controller-of-the-all-the-pages-where-this-directive-is-used.js

```
$scope.$on('handleBroadcast', function() {
        $scope.notify = menuClick.notify;
});
```

I don't know how patch the whole stuff in the directive itself so that repetition of the above code in all the controllers could be avoided. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand your question but I see you're making separate modules for each part of your app :) great to see more people doing this. I have an example that I put together [here](https://github.com/joeLloyd/DoingAngularRight). Look into app/shared/navigation-bar. Here you will find a directive that I built to add the navbar and controler . Hope this helps

Comment: @JoeLloyd there's only one module in OP code, not sure what you mean by *separate modules*

Comment: @charlietfl ah I just read his module name, I was distracted. My bad. But take a look at my example anyway you can see a directive and how features become modules.

Comment: @JoeLloyd fully understand using modules for features but it's not really relevant to OP's situation

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the ideal answer but will help you understand how to use service to share methods.

Move the function declaration for `$scope.handleMenuClick` from controller to your service:

```
.factory('menuClick', function($rootScope) {
    var sharedService = {};
    sharedService.notify = {};
     // new function 
     sharedService.handleMenuClick = function(action) {
        sharedService.notify.warningNotify =  true;
        .......
        if(!action.IsEnabled)
        .......
     }
     .....
     return sharedService 
})
```

Then in controller you only need a *reference* to the method in service:

```
$scope.handleMenuClick = menuClick.handleMenuClick;
```

Comment: ThankYou but you still needs to repeat $scope.handleMenuClick = menuClick.handleMenuClick; to every controller don't you?

Comment: not necessarily if menu is put into directive or simply uses it's own controller. We don't know how you have your views set up

Comment: Well yes for both. Menu has been put into a directive and has it'e own controller.

Comment: Also note that you don't have to copy every property of service object to controller but can still use properties in view